# Why do some scans end up with light and dark horizontal stripes in them?

Tags: scanner

I have noticed that sometimes when I scan a negative on my Epson V600 scanner, the resulting scan has light and dark horizontal stripes around the edges of objects in the image. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong when I make the scan, and if there's a way to avoid ending up with stripes in the image.

Below is a screenshot of a scan blown up 600%. It was sharpened afterward in Photoshop 7. The stripes are there before sharpening, but they're less noticeable.
[image]

Comment: Did the paper move in the scanner feeder while you were scanning?

Comment: The above comment means "film"...

Comment: Thank you - I missed that. Did the material being scanned move?    If not the scanner has a hardware issue.

Comment: It could just be the optics of the scanner itself. And nothing can help fix that except upgrading the scanner.

Comment: No, the negative didn't move.

Comment: Then you need to get the scanner serviced - hardware error.